# Change data capture async triggers don't get all the events when doing multiple record operations on the same execution thread

Tags: change-data-capture, async-trigger

After doing more than one operation in a single transaction, the change data capture event trigger does not get the two expected events.

For example, we will create and update a Lead in the same transaction:

```
Lead myLead = new Lead();
myLead.Name = 'test';
insert myLead;
myLead.Name = 'updated';
update myLead;
```

A trigger created in the LeadChangeEvent object gets the following record in its Trigger.New map:

- Lead: Operation=INSERT, Id=00QXXXXXXXXXX, Name='**updated**'

While this could be somehow considered as an expected behavior, it doesn't do the job of offloading work from the transactional triggers as the expected events aren't received.

Another example:

```
Lead myLead = new Lead();
myLead.Name = 'test';
insert myLead;
myLead.Name = 'updated';
update myLead;
delete myLead;
```

This doesn't trigger any CDC events **at all**.

At the end, we created our own change events framework using a triggerHandler, platform events and a record field as a flag for execution, but the question is: ¿Did we miss something in our implementation?.